# Build Failures in react-native-safe-area-context Library

Tags: android, react-native, build, kotlin-gradle-plugin, react-native-safe-area-view

**Issue Summary:**
I'm encountering build failures when trying to integrate the react-native-safe-area-context library into my Android project. The build fails with the following error messages:

FAILURE: Build completed with 2 failures.

### 1: Task failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'F:\AssigmentForCompany\Android\UserManager\node_modules\react-native-safe-area-context\android\build.gradle' line: 35
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-safe-area-context'.

> Could not initialize class org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinGradleBuildServices

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

### 2: Task failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-safe-area-context'.

> compileSdkVersion is not specified. Please add it to build.gradle

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> ==============================================================================

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 36s

Here is build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    def kotlin_version = rootProject.ext.has('kotlinVersion') ? rootProject.ext.get('kotlinVersion') : project.properties['RNSAC_kotlinVersion']

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version")
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:6.11.0")
    }
}

if (project == rootProject) {
    apply from: "spotless.gradle"
    return
}


def getExtOrDefault(name, defaultValue) {
    return rootProject.ext.has(name) ? rootProject.ext.get(name) : defaultValue
}

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
    // - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
    // - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
    // - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
    apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"
}

android {
    def agpVersion = com.android.Version.ANDROID_GRADLE_PLUGIN_VERSION
    if (agpVersion.tokenize('.')[0].toInteger() >= 7) {
        namespace "com.th3rdwave.safeareacontext"
    }

    compileSdkVersion getExtOrDefault('compileSdkVersion', 30)

    // Used to override the NDK path/version on internal CI or by allowing
    // users to customize the NDK path/version from their root project (e.g. for M1 support)
    if (rootProject.hasProperty("ndkPath")) {
        ndkPath rootProject.ext.ndkPath
    }
    if (rootProject.hasProperty("ndkVersion")) {
        ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion getExtOrDefault('minSdkVersion', 16)
        targetSdkVersion getExtOrDefault('targetSdkVersion', 28)
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()

        ndk {
            abiFilters (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }

    lintOptions{
        abortOnError false
    }

    packagingOptions {
        // For some reason gradle only complains about the duplicated version of libreact_render libraries
        // while there are more libraries copied in intermediates folder of the lib build directory, we exclude
        // only the ones that make the build fail (ideally we should only include libsafeareacontext_modules but we
        // are only allowed to specify exclude patterns)
        exclude "**/libreact_render*.so"
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        java {
            if (isNewArchitectureEnabled()) {
                srcDirs += [
                    "src/fabric/java",
                    "${project.buildDir}/generated/source/codegen/java"
                ]
            } else {
                srcDirs += [
                    "src/paper/java"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}

def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : [
        "armeabi-v7a",
        "x86",
        "x86_64",
        "arm64-v8a"
    ]
}

repositories {
    google()
    maven {
        // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
        url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android"
    }
    mavenCentral()
}

def kotlin_version = getExtOrDefault('kotlinVersion', project.properties['RNSAC_kotlinVersion'])

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
}
```

This is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "UserManager",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.9.13",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.24.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.11",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
}
```

**What I Tried:**

I deleted the cache using the ./gradlew cleanBuildCache command in the project's root directory.
I reinstalled the necessary dependencies.
I attempted to run the app again using the react-native run-android command.

**Expected Outcome:**

I expected the cache deletion to clear any potential issues related to the build cache.
I anticipated that reinstalling the dependencies and rerunning the app would result in a successful build.

**Actual Result:**

Despite taking these actions, the build process still failed to complete successfully.
The same error messages persisted, indicating issues with the react-native-safe-area-context library and the compileSdkVersion.

Comment: any update on this?